# FireFox and <a href scrolling to a page part like div

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I have a style for image button :

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: 120%;
  z-index: 1;
}
@media screen and (min-device-width : 100px) and (max-width: 600px)  {
 .sticky{
 display:none;
 }
}
```

and script for these:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    myFunction();

}

var backarrow = document.getElementById("back");
var sticky = backarrow.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    backarrow.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    backarrow.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
```

}

it actually works! But I do not understand why Clicking is disabled for FireFox while other browsers do not have problems with it. z-index is set to 1 but other browsers are fine with it but FF. what I can do about it and how to fix it?
Thank you very much who knows!

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of the HTML? i.e. for this 'image button' & for whatever element id="back" is? Also - what do you mean or how do you know "clicking is disabled in Firefox", i.e. I don't see any onclick events...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!!!!!!!!!!
What I did is used my button id for my jquery script insted of img id. Thus, entire button would scroll down insted of only image and therefore I could implement

```
 <button onClick="location.href = '#top'"
```

insted of  any
 `<img onclick` or `<href onclick`
 events that I tried and do not work.
Hope it helps anybody too as example:)

Answer (score 0):

I just did this for image buttons  links:

```
<a href="#top"   <a href="#wrap"
```

Supposed to work for any browser. This even not a script. but probably not good css enough that I have.

'>

```
<img alt="" class="mainlogo"  src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("******.png")); ?> '>

   <button class="right"> <a href="#wrap" class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"> <img alt="" id="forward" class="logo" style='max-width: 40px;' src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("*****/Pictur3.png")); ?>  '> </a> </button>
```